# SQLite delete where clause arguments

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, where-clause

I am new to Sqlite. Prior I tried deleting a row in my table using trick_id

```
public void deleteTrick (int trick_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(Constants.TRICKS_TABLE, Constants.TRICK_ID + " ?= ", new String[]{ String.valueOf(trick_id)});
    db.close();
}
```

but now I need to delete row based on two constraints trick_id and opn_id.

How to use 'where clause' to delete the row that matches with same opn_id & trick_id that are passed in as parameters to delete method?

```
public void deleteTrick (int trick_id,int opn_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(Constants.TRICKS_TABLE, Constants.TRICK_ID + " ?= " WHERE Constants.OPN_ID + " ?= ", new String[]{ String.valueOf(trick_id), String.valueOf(opn_id)};
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Does it not work when you use "id = <id> AND otherId = <otherId>"?

Comment: Your delete command looks randomly built (or defaced by a so-called "Markov ape", if you know what I'm talking about).

Answer (score 2):

to delete :

```
db.delete(TableName,ID_that_you_want_to_delete + " =?" , new String[]{your id that given for delete }) ;



db.delete(Constants.TRICKS_TABLE, Constants.TRICK_ID + " =? ",new String[]{String.valueOf(opn_id)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delete method like this

```
  public void deleteTrick() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(Constants.TRICKS_TABLE, null, null);
    db.close();
}
```

In this codes first **null** is your WHERE clause,and second **null** is your Whereargs.If my answer is correct you can accept.Happy coding:)